# Why my composable not recomposing on changing value for MutableState of HashMap?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why my composable not recomposing on changing value for MutableState of HashMap.

ViewModel

```
 val imageList: MutableState<HashMap<Int, Uri>> = mutableStateOf(HashMap())
    fun setImage(imageUri: Uri) {
        imageList.value[imagePosition] = imageUri
    }
```

Fragment

```
if (viewModel.imageList.value[stepNo] != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(
                                            viewModel.imageList.value[stepNo].toString()
                                        )
                                    ) {
                                        Image(
                                            contentDescription = "Recipe",
                                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_fastfood_24),
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .padding(8.dp)
                                        )
                                    }

fun permissionCallbacks() {
        imagePickerListener =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    val selectedImageUri = data?.data
                    selectedImageUri?.let { viewModel.setImage(it) }
                }
            }
        requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
            ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
                if (isGranted) {
                    val galleryIntent = Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    )
                    galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
                    imagePickerListener?.launch(galleryIntent)
                } else {
                   
                }
            }
    }
```

I see by debugging that value correctly set inside `setImage()` method but if condition for `viewModel.imageList.value[stepNo]` is not called again when value for hashmap is changed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mutableStateOf` can only track when you replace one value with an other one. If you change state of current value no way it can handle it

You can use `mutableStateMapOf` instead of `mutableStateOf(HashMap())`:

```
val imageList = mutableStateMapOf<Int, Uri>()
---
fun setImage(imageUri: Uri) {
    imageList[imagePosition] = imageUri
}
```

Comment: I am getting warning - Creating a state object during composition without using remember

Comment: @Paritosh this code example expected to be placed in a view model. If you wanna use it inside a composable, then yes, you need `remember`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, well firstly, the initialisation logic you are using contains boilerplate. I mean if you are writing `val a = 0`, then it is good. You do not need to specify the type here. `val a : Int = 0` is wrong (practically, not technically). In your initialisation, you do not need to include `MutableState<...>`; you can specify the type of hashmap in the `HashMap()` call in the `mutableStateOf(...)`.

Ok, secondly, you cannot treat any type of data as state (I mean compose cannot). You can instead try to use primitive types as your store, or check if there exists an exact type for your needs, **that is pre-built** in Compose.

For example,

`val a by mutableStateOf("Hello")`

will trigger recompositions, while

`val a by mutableStateOf(Path())`

will not, even if you re-assign the whole variable. This is because `Path()` is not meant to be a state-holder in Compose.

If you actually replace the map of Int and Uri, with two lists of Int and Uri each, it will work as expected because even the immutable `listOf()` is supported.

Now, you could also search if a particular pre-defined holder supports your use case. In this case, like there has been `mutableStateListOf()` added to the libraries, allowing you to use lists directly as a regular list object while still being a state-holder.

Philip says there's mutableStateMapOf(), which I haven't heard of but since there's `mutableStateListOf()`, it might be there too.

So yes, for your use case, if it exists, it will work properly, but you should know why the HashMap didn't work, which is why I posted the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SnapshotStateMap` instead of HashMap:

[image]