# How can I make my Composable Recompose with a For Loop Update?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I understand that architecturally this is definitely not a good thing to do, but I have embedded a for loop in a composable to update state as follows:

```
@Composable
fun WorkScreen(name: String?) {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = "YOU PRESSED ME $text")
    }
    for (i in 1..100) {
        text = i
    }
}
```

My expectation is that when I switch to this screen the for loop should update the mutableState and hence cause a recomposition which causes the time to tick up. However, instead I just get `YOU PRESSED ME 0` if I put the for loop below the `Box` function, or I get `YOU PRESSED ME 100` if I put it above the `Box` function.

The following question: [Why my composable not recomposing on changing value for MutableState of HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871551/why-my-composable-not-recomposing-on-changing-value-for-mutablestate-of-hashmap), does seem to be quite similar, but I'm not sure how it applies here. It seems to me I am updating the text value to be `i`!

Comment: The result should be 'YOU PRESSED ME 100', in both cases I think.

Comment: How often do you want the text to update? Once a second? Once a millisecond? Instantaneously?

Comment: @MARSK No in the one case it's 0, and the other it's 100.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ideally I would like it once a second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change view state directly from the composable view builder, because compose functions will be recalled often during recomposition, so your calculation will be repeated. You should use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) instead.

If you need to show dynamic change of the value to user, then you should use animation, as Gabriele's answer suggests.

An other option is updating the value manually. Inside [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) you can use suspend functions, so you can change the value with a needed delay:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    for (i in 1..100) {
        delay(1000) // update once a second
        text = i
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the launched effect option is basically just a way of showing animation to some value inside of a composable?

Comment: @Connor It's just a way of changing the state, it doesn't really animate anything

Comment: Okay cool! That was poorly worded, but I think what I meant to say was: "A launched effect can only really be used to affect the appearance of a composable, not to interact with other parts of your app.". Is that correct?

Comment: I would recommend you visit the link to [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) he has mentioned in the answer. It would explain everything.

Comment: Also maybe take the [state codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#5) if you haven't already.

Comment: @Connor You can interact with other parts of the app with `LaunchedEffect`. I agree with MARSK that you should check on documentation for details

Answer (score 2):

You should use an animation where you define how often you want to update the text applying it with a [side effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

For example:

```
var targetValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val value by animateIntAsState(
    targetValue = targetValue,
    animationSpec = tween( durationMillis = 2000 )
)

Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text(text = "YOU PRESSED ME $value")
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    targetValue = 100
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you possible explain to me why what I'm doing won't work?